# GORM - get raw DB value for domain class properties

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, getter

I'm using GORM for MongoDB in my Grails 3 web-app to manage read/writes from DB.

I have the following 2 domain classes:

```
class Company {
  String id
}

class Team {
  String id
  Company company
}
```

For teams, their company is saved on DB as String, and with GORM I can simply use `team.company` to get an instance of `Company` domain class.

However, I need to override the getter for `company`, and I need the raw value for company id (as stored on DB), without GORM getting in the way and performing its magic.
Is there a way to get the raw String value?

Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance

---

**Update (May 27)**

Investigating @TaiwaneseDavidCheng suggestion, I updated my code to

```
class Company {
  String id
}

class Team {
  String id
  Company company
  String companyId

  static mapping = {
    company       attr: "company"    // optional
    companyId     attr: "company", insertable: false, updateable: false
  }
}
```

Please note that I'm using GORM for MongoDB, which (citing the [manual](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/index.html#compatibility)) `tries to be as compatible as possible with GORM for Hibernate`, but requires a slightly different implementation.

However I found out (by trial&error) that GORM for MongoDB doesn't support a similar solution, as it seems only one property at a time can be mapped to a MongoDB document property.
In particular the last property in alphabetical order wins, e.g. `companyId` in my example.

---

I figured out a way to make the whole thing work, I'm posting my own answer below.

Comment: Why not just do `team.company.id`?

Comment: Because needing to override the getter for team's company (`getCompany()`) I cannot use `company.id` from within the getter itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Follows the edit to my question above)*

I defined a custom mapping, and made use of Grails [transients](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html) by also defining custom getter and setter for team's company.

```
class Company {
  String id
}

class Team {
  String id
  Company company
  String companyId

  static mapping = {
    companyId     attr: "company"    // match against MongoDB property
  }

  static transients = [ 'company' ]  // non-persistent property

  Company getCompany() {
    return Company.get(companyId)
  }
  void setCompany(Company company) {
    companyId = company.id
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

given a non-insertable non-updateable column "companyId" in domain class

```
class Company {
  String id
}

class Team {
  String id
  Company company
  Long companyId
  static mapping = {
    company               column:"companyId"
    companyId               column:"companyId",insertable: false,updateable: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Though not working in my case (check the edit to my question above), it really helped me to find a solution.